# How do you create a pointer to an object property in javascript?

Tags: javascript

If I have an object like this:

```
obj = {a:{aa:1}, b:2};
```

and I want to create a shortcut variable (pointer to obj.a.aa) x like this:

```
x = obj.a.aa;
```

and then I want to assign the value 3 to obj.a.aa using x like this:

```
x = 3;  // I would like for obj.a.aa to now equal 3
console.log(obj.a.aa); // 1  (I want 3)
```

How can I set x up to result in the value 3 going into obj.a.aa?

I understand that obj.a.aa is a primitive, but how can I define a variable that points to it which I can then use to assign a value to the property?

Comment: pretty sure you can't.

Comment: Related: [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language) and [Does JavaScript pass by reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104494/does-javascript-pass-by-reference)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot use x = value as that will not keep any references, just a copy. You would have to reference the parent branch in order to do so:

```
x = obj.a;
```

then set the value:

```
x.aa = 3;
```

Comment: So I have to stay one level higher than the property value by always referencing the direct parent object?

Comment: @ChrisG. For value types yes.

Answer (score 3):

Or, use a function:

```
var set_x = function(val){
  obj.a.aa = val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can't - you're not trying to modify the reference that is the name of the object property, you're trying to modify the **object**. To modify the object, you'll need a reference to the object.

That being said there's probably a creative way to do this. Create a function that takes as a constructor the object, and give the function a customer `=` setter or method that modifies the object reference. Something like this might work.